# how to display total registered admin or users count saperately?

Tags: php, sql

here is coading where i want to display total registered admins or users sapraterty in numbers. but in this coading it shows the total admins+users quantity. but i want to dispay only users count or saprately admins count what is the coading to get saperate admins and users count??

```
<?php  
             $query = "SELECT id FROM register ORDER BY id";  //here i have table name register where i put a column Name "usertypes" which stores values like admin or user i have multiple admins and users

             $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

             $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);

             echo '<h4> Total Admin: '.$row.'</h4>';
           ?>
```

Comment: now try with my updated answer pleas & let me know what happens??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :-**
you have to use **count()** function with **IF** condition in SQL QUERY.

```
<?php  

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register");
 $query = "select
                COUNT(if(usertypes='admin',1,NULL)) as admin,
                COUNT(if(usertypes='user',1,NULL)) as user
                from register";

 $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($query_array= mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)){
                   $admin = $query_array['admin']; 
                   $user = $query_array['user']; 
                   
 echo '<h4> Total Admin: '.$admin.'</h4>';
 echo '<h4> Total user: '.$user.'</h4>';
    
}
?>
```

**Note:-** (1). There is no need to use $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
(2).you have to use while Loop after execution of your sql Query.

Comment: please run this query in `phpmyadmin` and let me know what it count returns

Comment: still not wiorking still shows only one @kumar

Comment: no you done any mistake please check properly , i have tested query.

Comment: just echo your  `$query` and run it in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: please post your table structure.

Comment: yeah it run perfectly in phpmyadmin but it dosent work on page?

Comment: please post your table output as screen shoot.

Comment: can you plese write code to get same output? @kumar

Comment: your count logic works perfect in phpmyadmin but i cant get output on page can you sent code to get output?

Comment: i updated my answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps do ...

```
$query = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM register WHERE register.usertypes = 'admin'
```

Plus, doing COUNT helps you get rid of the additional line of code
 `$row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);`

Comment: this will get only admin count.

Comment: it shows only one admin but i have 5 admins right now?